# Windows Dual monitor settings

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am wondering if there is a setting that will allow me to launch windows when I open them on the "focused" monitor.

Currently when my mouse is focused on the second monitor (not the main one) and I hit the super key (or maybe windows key?) it opens the windows start menu on the main monitor, not the one my mouse is hovering on.

I am currently using windows 10. If any other information is needed please let me know and I will happily update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think that such fine-tuned behavior is only possible with 3rd-party software, so if you really need it, give a try to [Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/features/) (it implements a parallel taskbar for the second monitor) or [UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer (though not really what I wanted... Thanks microsoft :'D) I will try it out when I am sitting at that machine and report back!